# Google contacts api v3 refresh token via javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-oauth

Does anyone knows how to get google refresh and access token for google contacts api v3? I can authenticate, sync my contacts, but dunno what happens when my access token expires, and never get refresh token from google api.

Does anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How you deal with refresh depends on which "flow" you are using. If it's a Javascript/client flow, just get a new access token the same way you got the first one (probably by calling gapi.authorize).

If you're using server flow, you can use the same approach, or you can request and store a refresh token. To get a refresh token, specify "offline" in your original authorization request.

A general tip when using oauth... deal with the oauth stuff separately from the specific API you're using (contacts in your case). This page https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 (and the sub-links off it) contains all you need to know.